# Checking lines of a file against a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows

I am using the Regex.Match method to find a credit card number within a file (for PCI compliance)

I interate through the lines (strLine) of a file and check each one against a regex (m_strRegEx):

```
Regex.Match(strLine, m_strRegEx)

string strLine = "4111111111111111"
```

This works fine, but if the line contains other characters, for example strLine might =:

```
string strLine = "fhj*4111111111111111op)"
```

The regex does not then pick the cc number up, how would it be possible to overcome this issue?

The regex I am using is:

```
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

Comment: Firstly by showing us your regular expression, not the matching code.

Comment: @minitech, updated above

Comment: Why do you have a file with credit card numbers?

Comment: Gotta agree with @Nick Bray on that one!

Comment: Should `for PCI Compliance` read `For PCI non-compliance`?

Comment: Yup, keeping text files with credit card numbers is probably not very PCI compliant.

Comment: @NickBray: Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI) aims to control exposures of sensitive cardholder data. Even though I know nothing about OP's intentions, I would suggest that he's trying to check if the document contains sensitive data (e.g. card numbers) and signal that if it has. Anyway I wouldn't have been so suspicious.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your regex is *anchored* to the start and end of the string with `^` and `$`. This means that *the entire string* has to match your regex and not just a substring.

Remove the `^` and `$` from the regex to perform a substring match:

```
4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?
```

Quick test:

```
PS> 'fhj*4111111111111111op)' -match '4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?'; $Matches
True

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              4111111111111111
```

Answer (score 4):

As your regex starts with `^` and ends with `$` this means that the match must be from the start to the end of the line. Just remove these characters from your regex pattern and it should work as you require.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the anchors:

```
4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?
```